# How do you get terminal to echo / print all key strokes?

Tags: terminal

Looking to see what the terminal gets when you press keystrokes such as alt+a or whatever.

I remember there was a really simple way to do this with a one line command and without installing any extra software, but I can't seem to find it again.

Any one know?

Comment: This is under program/application control. It is on by default for most shell programs like bash and zsh. Are you using telnet or ssh? Some other program?

Answer (score -1):

Found it

`sed -n l`

Really useful for debugging problems with terminal programs that benefit from complex bindings like vim.

Or just use `cat` or `sed`

Comment: This just gets `sed` to echo its input, but doesn't execute any commands. You can get the same result with just running `cat`.

Comment: @patrix I'm including this in the answer, or if you want to make your own answer I'll accept it. Thanks!